# Dashed 3D plot: dashes run together

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

When I use the `Dashed` option in my 3D parametric plot, the dashing looks very muddy and the dashes are running together. For example, I plot the below code, right click and `Save Graphic As...` to pdf. Notice the dashed lines running together in different parts of the plot.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{l, l, l^2}, {l, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed},  
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 20}}, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

How can I fix this? I'm currently using Mathematica 9, not sure if this is still a problem in Mathematica 10.

[image: plot image]

Comment: On a mac and v10 it looks as you'd expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also on a Mac with v10 and see no issues. Perhaps you could try using [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) and experimenting with the [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) and [`ImageResolution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResolution.html) settings.

```
Export["~/Desktop/imgTEMP-800-300.pdf", plot1, ImageSize -> 800, ImageResolution -> 300]
```